# Quickblox android facebook login issue

Tags: android, quickblox

I have implemented facebook login in my app, in which I also use `Quickblox` but I seem to have a problem.

The regular way a user signs up is by `username + password + email`. The problem is when I try implementing the quickblox's method for facebook login it does not link the facebook account to a possibly existing regular account. Meaning, if a user already has an account but desires to login by facebook, it does not log in with his existing account but creates a new one.

Here's the facebook login method from quickblox:

```
QBUsers.signInUsingSocialProvider(QBProvider.FACEBOOK, session.getAccessToken(), null, new QBCallbackImpl() {

    @Override
    public void onComplete(Result result) {
        if(result.isSuccess()) {
            QBUserResult qbUserResult = (QBUserResult) result;
            Log.d("LogIn was successful","user: " + qbUserResult.getUser().toString());
        } else {
            Log.e("Errors",result.getErrors().toString());
        }
    }

});
```

Now, I thought of something else... what if as soon as I get the OK from facebook OAUTH, I get the facebook email, check if it's in my database and then log it in manually, without the "special" facebook login provided by quickblox. But then I hit another wall: I can't do it because the users' password are not accessible. I desperately need help, any will be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: any solutions . I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean saying "it does not link the facebook account to a possibly existing regular account." You mean user with same email already exists on QB ? If you want link FB account to existing on QB user you should do these steps:

1. authenticate as regular user on QB
2. auth/signIN UsingSocialProvider